# Multithreading programming with python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am doing a little bit of python multithreading programming and found the result of my code vary strange, not parallel at all (8 cores, 8 threads, 13% cpu utilization). Then I have found a python GIL term and these slides (http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf). Is it real that python is not parallelizable?
Will the multiprocessing module help to utilize computational resources or there is another performance issue with that?

Comment: Which multithreading library did you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821477/python-code-performance-decreases-with-threading

Comment: @Nebril I use standard threading module can you recommend something else. Because spawning new processes does not really fit me.

Comment: @itun as Reut wrote: try multiprocessing https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Nebril - it's also mentioned in the docs. Atleast for python 2: *If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing*

Comment: Praise the docs then!

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global
>   Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once
>   (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome
>   this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of
>   the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to
>   use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model
>   if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

A a general rule of thumb:

When your bottleneck is I/O (like writing to disk...) - consider [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) which allows the program to keep running elsewhere when something is blocking an execution path.

When your bottleneck is cpu power, consider [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which allows cpu utilization.

Comment: what should I do if I cannot spawn new processes? Is there any 3rd party library to use threads in a usual sense.

Comment: You should drop by the python room for advices on what to do, instead of starting an opinion-based discussion here. The chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python